# Find out Room Availability For a Given Range of dates in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make it simple. Please read it and give me solution. I am totally stuck.

My room Table is

```
Id  RoomType  Total
1   Single     3
2   Double     2
```

I have Booking Table( b - Booked, c- checked-in, o checked-out, x-cancelled)

```
Id  CustName  FromDate    ToDate      RoomType TotalRoom  Status
1  Cust-1    2020-03-28  2020-03-29   Single      1         b 
2  Cust-2    2020-03-28  2020-03-31   Single      1         c
3  Cust-3    2020-03-28  2020-03-31   Single      1         c
```

**All Single rooms are in use now**

Scenario -1
I am searching for all occupied rooms with status b or c Date range (2020-03-28 to 2020-03-31)
Expecting result

```
   #  CustName  FromDate    ToDate      RoomType TotalRoom  Status
   1  Cust-1    2020-03-28  2020-03-29   Single      1         b  
   2  Cust-2    2020-03-28  2020-03-31   Single      1         c  
   3  Cust-3    2020-03-28  2020-03-31   Single      1         c  

                      OR
```

Result can be like one below also

```
    #  CustName  Date         RoomType  TotalRoom  Status
    1  Cust-1    2020-03-28   Single      1         b  
    2  Cust-1    2020-03-29   Single      1         b 

    3  Cust-2    2020-03-28   Single      1         c 
    4  Cust-2    2020-03-29   Single      1         c 
    5  Cust-2    2020-03-30   Single      1         c 
    6  Cust-2    2020-03-31   Single      1         c 

    7  Cust-3    2020-03-28   Single      1         c 
    8  Cust-3    2020-03-29   Single      1         c 
    9  Cust-3    2020-03-30   Single      1         c 
   10  Cust-3    2020-03-31   Single      1         c
```

Scenario -2
I am searching for all free rooms with Date range (2020-03-28 to 2020-03-31)
 
Expecting result

```
   #   CustName  FromDate    ToDate      RoomType TotalRoom  Status
   1   ""        2020-03-29  2020-03-31   AnyType
```

See from 29 to 31 for 3 days room is vacant which can be filled in by any type of rooms

```
                              OR
```

Result can be like one below also

```
    #  CustName  Date         RoomType  TotalRoom  Status 
    1  ""        2020-03-29   AnyType                      
    2  ""        2020-03-30   AnyType 
    3  ""        2020-03-31   AnyType
```

Scenario -3
I am searching for all free rooms with Date range (2020-03-28 to 2020-04-03)
 
Expecting result

```
       #  CustName   FromDate    ToDate      RoomType TotalRoom  status
       1  ""        2020-03-29   2020-04-03   Any type                 



                      or
```

Result can be like one below

```
   #  CustName  Date         RoomType  TotalRoom  Status
   1  ""        2020-03-29    Any type                 
   2  ""        2020-03-30    Any type                      
   3  ""        2020-03-31    Any type                       
   4  ""        2020-04-01    Any type                     
   5  ""        2020-04-02    Any type                      
   6  ""        2020-04-03    Any type
```

How to achieve this. I need your help Friends.

Comment: With mysql 8 you can create a list of dataes and numbers (CTE) and join them against your ocuucpied list and where there are no data Occupied is NULL you goz your vacancys, In older versions it is much more complicated, to create this list of dates on the fly

Comment: @nbk. thank you. but I am asking you Any possible way or other way round

Comment: Dear Friends Could you please help me

Comment: The first is easy SELECT * 
FROM 
  booking
  WHERE
  (FromDate BETWEEN '2020-03-28' AND '2020-03-31'
  OR ToDate BETWEEN '2020-03-28' AND '2020-03-31')
  AND Status IN ('b','c');  se  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ihwaUZpdhBvd4vhTqQAVsG/0 For the other is it as i told you before, so you have to put in soeme effort